# Ag Grid disable editing on key press

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In Ag-Grid how can i disable editing for an **Edit Key Pressed** and for **Printable Key Pressed** ? I need to edit a row only when i call **api.startEditingCell()**. I haven't found in the [Documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0).

Answer (score 4):

The `editable` column property can be either a boolean, or a function.

You could set editable to be a function that returns false by default, and true once you've initiated editing via some external process/action

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress all keys via [suppressKeyboardEvent](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#suppressKeyboardEvents)

```
const suppressKeyboardEvent = (params: SuppressKeyboardEventParams) => {
    const SuppressKeyWhileNoEdit = [".", "/", "*", "-", "+", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]; // disallow numpad keys but still allow numpad control keys

    const alphaKeys = ["KeyA", "KeyB", "KeyC", "KeyD", "KeyE", "KeyF", "KeyG", "KeyH", "KeyI", "KeyJ", "KeyK", "KeyL", "KeyM", "KeyN", "KeyO", "KeyP", "KeyQ", "KeyR", "KeyS", "KeyT", "KeyU", "KeyV", "KeyW", "KeyX", "KeyY", "KeyZ"];
    const digitKeys = ["Digit0", "Digit1", "Digit2", "Digit3", "Digit4", "Digit5", "Digit6", "Digit7", "Digit8", "Digit9"];
    const specialKeys = ["Backquote", "Minus", "Equal", "Backspace", "BracketLeft", "BracketRight", "Semicolon", "Quote", "Backslash", "Comma", "Period", "Slash", "IntlBackslash", "Delete"];

    const SuppressCodeWhileNoEdit = alphaKeys.concat(digitKeys.concat(specialKeys));

    const keyPressKey = params.event.key;
    const keyPressCode = params.event.code;

    return !params.editing && (SuppressCodeWhileNoEdit.includes(keyPressCode) || SuppressKeyWhileNoEdit.includes(keyPressKey));
};
```